# Appium Inspector displaying the wrong JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, selenium, environment-variables, appium, appium-android

Appium Inspector seems to think my [JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Lze.png)

However, [JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_341](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KRub.png)

Which is probably why I think I am unable to start the appium session getting this message:

> Original error: The 'java.exe' binary could not be found neither in PATH nor under JAVA_HOME (C:\Program Files\Java\bin)

I also have %JAVA_HOME%\bin in my PATH, so I'm unable to figure out why appium is detecting the wrong path for my JAVA_HOME variable. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sounds like it's looking for run-time (JRE) not the JDK.   You could probably just re-install Java JRE to fix this.

Comment: if installing the JRE doesn't help, check your PATH environmental variable to be sure it's pointing to the "bin" directory that contains "java.exe".  (and double-check it for multiple entries)

Comment: No experience with Appium, but this problem is not unique for that scenario. How exactly to you start the Appium Inspector?

Comment: @pcalkins I figured it out appium just had a seperate config pannel for environment variables that I needed to correct. Thank you for the help though

Comment: @cyberbrain it's through a GUI separately installed from appium. but I figured it out appium just had a separate config panel for environment variables that I needed to correct. Thank you for the help though

Comment: If possible I would recommend not to set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` in that configuration but try to use the "incoming" value from the operating system. This is no value that is dependent on an installed application - if you don't include a JDK in your installation as well.